# How can I increment a value in a bash script array by 1?

Tags: arrays, bash, increment

I'm trying to increment a value in an array by 1 using the following code, however I'm having some problems with it. Please can someone help me out?

```
myArray[$position]=((${myArray[$position]}++))
```

Comment: What's a unix array?  Are you scripting here or something?

Comment: That correct - I'm writing a bash script

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this

```
 myArr[3]=7
 (( myArr[3]++ ))
 echo ${myArr[3]}

 # output
 8
```

The `(( .... ))` can perform bash/ksh's math operations, and the variables referenced inside, don't need to be passed out as in your example, you're probably thinking of a similar construct `var=$(( ... MathStuff ...)) OR var=$( ... stringStuff ... )` (note the '$' before the opening paren).

Also note that inside `(( ... ))` you don't need to use the leading '$' for any math variables like $pct or $counter. If you're using arguments to the script or a function like $1, $2, ... $N, THEN you need to use the $, so the value of $1 is used, instead of just '1'. Thanks to @ChrisDown   for the reminder!

I hope this helps.

Comment: Not true, there are some times where you will have to refer to them with a leading `$` to force the context (`$1`, `$2` ... `$N`).

Comment: Great, that would certainly affect someones results. I'll update when I get back. Thanks for the improvement!

Comment: Note that [the exit status will be non-zero](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32250/why-does-a-0-let-a-return-exit-code-1/32251#32251) if `myArr[3]` is `0` before updating.

Comment: You can also use `let myArr[3]++`.

Answer (score 0):

Increment and update:

```
array[1]=$((array[1]++))
```